# Magento blocks and sub blocks are not rendering using type="core/text_list"

Tags: php, magento

I have to create a custom block that has sub block on it for a specific product page that display different data. I put it on the Custom Layout Update however my blocks are not displayed.

This is my block code

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="torque.tester-1" as="tt_1">
        <block type="core/template" name="torque.tester.ft.lbs" template="catalog/product/list/torque-tester.phtml">
            <action method="setData"><key>category_id</key><value>162</value></action>
            <action method="setData"><key>label</key><value>Standard Accuracy +1</value></action>
        </block>
        <block type="core/template" name="torque.tester.ft.in" template="catalog/product/list/torque-tester2.phtml">
            <action method="setData"><key>category_id</key><value>163</value></action>
            <action method="setData"><key>label</key><value>Standard Accuracy +2</value></action>
        </block>
        <block type="core/template" name="torque.tester.ft.oz" template="catalog/product/list/torque-tester3.phtml">
            <action method="setData"><key>category_id</key><value>164</value></action>
            <action method="setData"><key>label</key><value>Standard Accuracy +3</value></action>
        </block>
    </block>
</reference>
```

This is how I fetch it in view.phtml.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tt_1'); ?>
```

I want to call the parent block together with its sub block together as one.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you any error in logs files ? 

You module configuration is valid ? 

If you have a `Mage_Core_Exception` with message `Invalid block type` you can try change `<block type="core/text_list" name="torque.tester-1" as="tt_1">` to `<block type="core/template" name="torque.tester-1" as="tt_1">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <layout version="0.1.0">
     <default>
      <reference name="root">
       <block type="core/text_list" name="torque.tester-1" as="tt_1" translate="label">
        <label>My extra block</label>
       </block>
      </reference>
     </default>
```

more info can be found here [Inchoo - custom reference structural block](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-reference-structural-block/)